# iframe containing three.js canvas crashes on mobile

Tags: css, iframe

My site www.stefaniefranciotti.com functions as intended on desktop, but on mobile the full screen iframe containing a three.js canvas crashes the site.  The three.js canvas has a 3d object in it that the user can rotate around, on mobile it sort of scoots off the screen.  I have the iframe styled as follows:

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="my-fluid-container">
            <div class="intrinsic-container">
                    <iframe src="stefhead.html" name="stefhead" frameborder="0"  scrolling="no"  allowfullscreen ><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
            <div class="header-content-inner wow fadeIn text-center">
                <h1 class="awesome">Stefanie Franciotti</h1>
                <hr>
                <p style= "color: gray; font-weight: 400;font-size: 16px;margin-bottom: 50px;">UI/UX designer in NYC.</p>
                <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="password.html">
                <INPUT TYPE="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" VALUE="Resume & Portfolio">
                </FORM>     
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

css:

```
body { padding-top: 70px;
font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
height: 100%;
}


.intrinsic-container {
position: relative;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

/* 16x9 Aspect Ratio */
.intrinsic-container-16x9 {
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

/* 4x3 Aspect Ratio */
.intrinsic-container-4x3 {
  padding-bottom: 75%;
}

.intrinsic-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;

} 




header {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
min-height: auto;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
background-position: center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-color: white;



}

header .header-content {
position: relative;
width:100%;
height: auto;
padding: 100px 15px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;

font-weight: 100;
}
h1{
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 4em;


}
header .header-content .header-content-inner hr {
margin: 30px auto;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
margin-bottom: 50px;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
color: gray;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
header {
    min-height: 100%;
}

header .header-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    padding: 0 50px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
margin-bottom: 50px;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
color: gray;
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!!! thank you

Comment: You wanted the 3d object to be on the screen on the mobile?

Comment: yes, but if it's not possible, I would like to just disable the iframe for mobile.

Comment: disabling will be easy you can use media query to do that. I cant see the 3d model on my device but i can see it rendering on dev tools on browsers. its odd.

Comment: do you have webGL enabled in your browser?

Comment: On my mobile device I don't think so

Comment: what would the media query to disable it be?

Answer (score 0):

To disable the iframe you can use this code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
iframe{display:none;}
}
```

you can change the screen width to whatever you want it to be.

Cheers